# Render prototype of a Collection type twice in Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

In a Symfony Form for a CollectionType with an `add` option is there a way to render the prototype twice? Or a clean (see below) way to set full path of the fields in the formView so I can render the prototype string twice with proper keys and `__name__` placeholder.

#### Use case:

I have a collection of items of a few types (ie. video slide, text slide, etc.) sharing the same type but varying wildly in HTML form presentation. So I have a separate 'Add xxxx' buttons to add new fields of specific types (add text slide, add video slide, etc.) linking to separate prototype strings. The problem is that when I try to use the common prototype as a render source I cannot render same field twice, so on the second button the prototype string has only fields not rendered for the first one.

#### Tried solutions:

I tried with setting full_name for the fields by hand but I don't know a clean non-hacky way to do it (I know I can set the blockPrefix but that's not enough).

The hacky way to do it is to create new form View and swap the keys like so. It works but is ridiculous:

```php
// EDIT: For nested fields (eg. radio buttons) you need to make 
// the swap recursive, hence copyFields method was added. 
// ALSO: I know it's not generalized in any way but it's a hack 
// and I hope to get rid of it. ;-) 

   private function getTimelinePrototypes(FormView $sourceFormView, int $num) {
        /** @var FormView */
        $timelinesFormView = $sourceFormView->children['timelines'];
        /** @var FormView */
        $tlProto = $timelinesFormView->vars['prototype'];
        
        $protoForms = []; 
        // GET FORM VIEWS FOR MULTI PROTOYPES:
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
            $targetForm = $this->createForm(TimelineType::class, null, [])->createView();
            $this->copyFields($tlProto, $targetForm);
            $protoForms[] = $targetForm;
        }
        return $protoForms;
    }

    private function copyFields (FormView $sourceForm, FormView $targetForm) {
        foreach($targetForm->children as $fieldKey => $targetField) {
            $sourceField = $sourceForm->children[$fieldKey];
            foreach(['full_name', 'id', 'name', 'cache_key', 'unique_block_prefix', 'block_prefixes', ] as $key) {
                $targetField->vars[$key] = $sourceField->vars[$key];
            }
            if (count($sourceField->children) > 0) {
                $this->copyFields($sourceField, $targetField);
            }
        }
    }
```